# .Net 6 Maui - Open Application in full screen mode (Windows)

Tags: .net, windows, .net-6.0, maui, fullscreen

Is it possible to open the application under .NET 6 Maui on Windows in full screen mode? This can be defined initially in the App.xaml.cs. Google did not yield any helpful results

**I have already tried the following approaches:**

1.

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    var window = new Window(activationState)
    {
        Content = new MainPage()
    };

    // Set the window to full-screen
    window.WindowState = WindowState.FullScreen; <= WindowState not found on property "window"

    return window;
}
```

2.

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage();

    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Windows)
    {
        var applicationView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        applicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put the following code in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
           
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                  });
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>  
        {  
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>  
            {  
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>  
                {  
                //    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;  
                    IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    Microsoft.UI.WindowId myWndId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);  
                    var _appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);  
                    _appWindow.SetPresenter(Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);   
                 //if you want to full screen, you can use this line
               // (_appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).Maximize();   
                //if you want to Maximize the window, you can use this line                    
                });  
            });  
        });
#endif
```

Or you can try to put the following code in the MainPage.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
                  var window = App.Current.Windows.FirstOrDefault().Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window;
                  IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                  Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
                  Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
                appWindow.SetPresenter(Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
            //   (appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).Maximize();
            // this line can maximize the window
#endif
      }
```

Comment:  we commited around the same time :) Didn't see your answer at first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be of use.

There is a discussion about this over [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5478).

The suggestion there is to:

```
MauiProgram.cs
#if WINDOWS
            // using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;
            // #if WINDOWS
            //            using Microsoft.UI;
            //            using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
            //            using Windows.Graphics;
            // #endif

    builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
    {
        events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
        {
            windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
            {
                window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
                var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                var id = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                var appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                {
                    case OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                        overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
                        overlappedPresenter.Maximize();
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Is this what your looking for?